# What does checkudata function do in Lua

Tags: function, lua, lua-table

`luaT_checkudata(L, 3, torch_Tensor);`

I saw this function and I'm not sure what it does or how to figure out the params.

Comment: [`void *luaT_checkudata (lua_State *L, int ud, const void *id)`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/lib/luaT/luaT.c#L274)